# Загрузка image на OpenCart с dir `admin`

Tags: php, opencart, загрузка

Всем привет. Работаю с OpenCart. У меня есть представленный ниже работающий на сайте функционал,  необходимо его перенести в dir `admin` OpenCart. Я перенес: в базу пишет, а папку с фото для нового продукта не создает... Путь `$target_file` отрисовывает `image/catalog/users/customer_1/product_339` . Этот код работает на самом сайте в dir `catalog`, а в dir `admin` нет...

Что я делаю не так?

```
 if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')) {

        $this->load->model('catalog/product'); // подключаем модель
        $this->request->post['image'] = $_FILES['image']['name']; // добавляем в POST параметр image
        $data['productID'] = $this->model_catalog_product->addProduct($this->request->post); /// get productID from model

        $target_file = "image/catalog/users/customer_" . $this->request->post['id_customer'] . "/product_" . $data['productID'];
        if (!file_exists($target_file)) {
            mkdir($target_file, 0777, true);
        }  // указываем папку на сервере для загрузки файлов
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file . "/" . basename($_FILES['image']["name"]));// загружаем 1 главное фото
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `DIR_IMAGE`из `config.php` вместо `image`, тогда гарантированно попадете в нужную Вам дирекорию:

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')) {
        $this->load->model('catalog/product'); // подключаем модель
        $this->request->post['image'] = $_FILES['image']['name']; // добавляем в POST параметр image
        $data['productID'] = $this->model_catalog_product->addProduct($this->request->post); /// get productID from model

        $target_file = DIR_IMAGE . "catalog/users/customer_" . $this->request->post['id_customer'] . "/product_" . $data['productID'];
        if (!file_exists($target_file)) {
            mkdir($target_file, 0777, true);
        }  // указываем папку на сервере для загрузки файлов
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file . "/" . basename($_FILES['image']["name"]));// загружаем 1 главное фото
  }
```